# mongodb $merge: do the _id share the same timestamps?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, uniqueidentifier

In a mongodb aggregation that `$merge` into a separate collection. Assuming I let mongodb auto-generate the `_id` field for each record.

Will those `ObjectID` have the same timestamp? I understand that beyond 16 million records at the same timestamp, mongodb does not guarantee the uniqueness of the ID.

So if my pipeline generates more than 16M records (~38 millions in my data), do I risk repeating IDs?

Comment: Were you Able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://betterprogramming.pub/is-the-id-property-in-mongodb-100-unique-f1eaa19522ba)

> If that many documents are generated at the same time, on the same machine, and the same process, two documents can share the same object ID.

This is very unlikely to happen.

Comment: Well, this is a single aggregation, so same machine and same process for sure. The part I'm not sure about is the "same time". I run the aggregation at a given time, the question is whether the final bulk `$merge` stage is considered to happen at a single timestamp, or is it a loop?

Comment: Do you have standalone setup?

Comment: No, cloud Atlas